# Creating an Alias for a server in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Considering we can create aliases for our tables such as

```
Select *
From tableA a
JOIN tableB b on b.key = a.key
```

But what about a Linked Server? For instance I have a stored procedure in our test environment like so:

```
Select *
From tableA a
JOIN tableB b on b.key = a.key
JOIN TestLinkedServer.MyDB.dbo.tableC c ON c.key = a.key
```

In production I would have to remember to rewrite this as:

```
Select *
From tableA a
JOIN tableB b on b.key = a.key
JOIN ProdLinkedServer.MyDB.dbo.tableC c ON c.key = a.key
```

I want to be able to create the stored procedure on production without having to remember to change the server name. Is something like this possible (This example of course doesn’t work):

```
DECLARE @Server AS VARCHAR(20) = 'TestLinkedServer.MyDB.DBO'


IF (SELECT @@SERVERNAME) <> 'LocalTestServer'
BEGIN
 SET @Server = 'ProdLinkedServer.MyDB.DBO'
END

Select *
From tableA a
JOIN table B b on b.key = a.key
JOIN @Server.tableC c ON c.key = a.key
```

Comment: Is your test environment actually linking to the same server used by your production environment?

Comment: It's best to have the **same** linked server name on DEV and PROD, even if the DEV linked server is pointing to DEV target server, and PROD linked server is pointing to PRO target server.

Comment: anything that does not reside directly in the database should be referenced by `SYNONYM`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of linked servers you can use Synonym

```
USE <db>
GO

CREATE SYNONYM <Desired name>
FOR <ProductionServer>.<Database>.<schema>.<SP / Table / Func / etc...>
GO

EXEC <Desired name> 
GO
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/synonyms/create-synonyms?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: the synonym should refer to the remote table - there is no SP involved here ;)